# how can I react to a Tkinter Slider being moved, and get its position?

Tags: python, tkinter, slider

how is it possible to use the slider of tkinter to change the `zoom` variable in this piece of code?

```
    zoom = 0.5
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    image = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx=zoom, fy=zoom)
```

I want to change the variable `zoom` with a tkinter slider. how can i do it?

Comment: please review [ask]. you need to attempt to solve your own question. this shows no effort expended, specifically no evidence that you even googled for any existing materials that teach you tkinter... -- further, please review [mre]. this issue is either about tkinter *or* about OpenCV. since you have no tkinter code, I'll assume that's your issue. you should have formulated a question that does not involve OpenCV then, because you seem to know how to use OpenCV, once you have a "slider value".

Comment: first you have to create tkinter window with slider and assing/bind function to this slider - and this function will be executed when slider change position and it may run `resize()`. So it would be simpler if you would create minimal working code and we could simply copy it and use it to create solution. Without code it is hard to say anything because GUIs don't work like text script and it need a lot of code. You can't do it with one line of code.